# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prepareStyles') in ListItem from material UI in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am making sure that the `rows` is filled and defined before using, but why is the error coming, i am not able to understand , it is been a week now , i am stuck here,

How to solve this please !

```
return isSmallScreen ? (
        <div>
            <List sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                {rows &&
                    rows.map((row) => (
                        <ListItem>
                            <ListItemText primary={row.name}></ListItemText>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
            </List>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <DataGrid
            className=""
            getRowId={(row) => row._id}
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={30}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[30]}
            disableSelectionOnClick
            experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
            autoHeight={true}
            autoPageSize={true}
            selectionModel={selectedRows}
            onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                setSelectedRows(ids);
            }}
        />
    );
```

Comment: Did you wrap your application with a `MuiThemeProvider`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem in this line:

```js
getRowId={(row) => row._id}
```

You are describe the function, but row isn't defined yet, so row._id will throw the error.

If it doesn't help, please provide us a little bit more information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try rows?.map , as on first render the row might be null and leter get its value.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem !